# Django forms with custom bootstrap layout

Tags: html, django, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm running Django 1.9 with Bootstrap. I use pure Django, without any crispy forms etc.
Some time ago I was struggling with forms customization under Bootstrap. My friend proposed me a solution. It's working, but for me it looks really heavy.

Is there any other, simpler way to make use of Django and Bootstrap forms?
What I need, is to populate values in form and send them successfuly to Django backend.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="price" class="form-control-label col-md-3">Price</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="number" class="form-control"
               value="{{ form.price.data|default:''  }}" 
               name='price' id='price' placeholder="Price">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can render your `{{ form }}` by each field in html form, whith bootstrap classes like in this example:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <div class ="col-md-6">{{ form.your_first_field }}</div> 
        <div class = "col-md-6">{{ form.your_second_field }}</div> 
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</form>
```

Or you can try another layout, follow by this logic